# How to set the partitions in topics in RocketMQ?

Tags: rocketmq

I am using RocketMq as a messaging layer for my application and I need to set the partitions in the topic created to one. How to set the number of partitions to topic in RocketMQ?

Answer (score 0):

RocketMQ does not have concept of partitions . What you need is queue numbers.

Just to create the same topics in different machines, you have have different partitions to write and read from.